# Ansible failed to run shell module on sbin folder

Tags: python-2.7, ansible, ansible-2.x

I ran Ansible Playbook on specific host:

When I execute for example `iptables -L` command from Ansible I got this error:

`changed: [host] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "iptables -L", "delta": "0:00:00.018402", "end": "2020-04-26 09:33:11.274857", "failed_when_result": false, "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 127, "start": "2020-04-26 09:33:11.256455", "stderr": "/bin/sh: iptables: command not found", "stderr_lines": ["/bin/sh: iptables: command not found"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}`

Example to playbook:

```
---
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - name: ls
      shell: tuned -v
      args:
         executable: /usr/sbin

    - name: iptables flush filter
      iptables:
        chain: "{{ item }}"
        flush: yes
      with_items:  [ 'INPUT', 'FORWARD', 'OUTPUT' ]

    - name: Get iptables rules | No resilience comment
      command: iptables -L
      become: yes
      args:
        executable: /sbin
```

Inventory file:

```
[hosts]
host
[all:vars]
ansible_user=ansible_user
ansible_become_user=root
ansible_ssh_pass=pass
ansible_become=yes
```

but the iptables is installed on the machine.
I check more command and i got that all the commands in `/sbin` folder not found.
What the reason ?! 
thanks for helping

Comment: You need to run your playbook as priviledged user(root/sudo) to run command in `/sbin` folder. which user is executing the playbook?

Comment: I ran with ```become=yes``` and args:
         executable: /sbin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> got that all the commands in /sbin folder not found. What the reason

Usual reason `$PATH` variable, which does not include `/sbin` location. The simplest solution is to use full path to binary you want to run, so instead of attempting to invoke `iptables` you need to use `/sbin/iptables`.

Alternatively, which may look like better solution as it does not require you to hardcode paths nor edit anything, you can set own `$PATH` for the whole playbook, as documented [in Ansible FAQ](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/faq.html):

```
environment:
  PATH: "{{ ansible_env.PATH }}:/thingy/bin"
  OTHER_ENV_VAR: its_new_value
```

Note the above example appends `/thingy/bin` path to existing value of `$PATH`. You may want to add it first, or replace existing PATH completely if needed though. Also note that `ansible_env` is normally populated by fact gathering (thus you must not disable it) and the value of the variables depends on the user that did the gathering action. If you change `remote_user` or `become_user` you might end up using the wrong/different values for those variables.

Comment: i execute this command on the machin ```echo $PATH```
and this is results: 
```/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/home/nftuser/bin```
it's look like /sbin include in $PATH.

Comment: Hi i ran this command from ansible so this is results from ansible:
```/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin``` 
/sbin not in the $PATH how i can add /sbin to $PATH ?
like this:
```- name: ls
      shell: iptables -L
      args:
        executable: /sbin/iptables
```

Comment: I can to change the ```$PATH ``` and add ```/sbin``` folder, cos I don't want to change all the tasks that use with ```/sbin``` commands manually

Comment: You can overide $PATH in the playbook. I edited my answer